# Angular 2: Service is not returning the values

Tags: angular

I am following a tutorial which has 2 use cases

1. Get the list products from the json file
2. Get the details of the clicked product by passing the product id.

The first part is working fine. But service class is not returning any results back when I click on a product. Sometimes service class returns the value but other time it throws:

```
Error: Error in ./ProductDetailComponent class ProductDetailComponent - inline template:31:22 caused by: Cannot read property 'productName' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'productName' of undefined
```

While debugging the issue, I can see that `productId` is being passed to the service layer successfully. It is a very straightforward implementation, not sure why it isn't working.
Service class looks like this:

```
private url: string = 'api/products/products.json';
  private product: IProduct;
  constructor(private http: Http){}


  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: '+JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getProduct(id: number): Observable<IProduct> {
    console.log("Id in service class: "+id)
    return this.getProducts()
      .map((products: IProduct[]) => products.find(p => p.productId===id));
  }
```

Rest of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/himanshuy/Acme-app/tree/master/src/app/product-list).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put `this.cd.markForCheck();` in your getProduct function of ProductDetailComponent [here](https://github.com/himanshuy/Acme-app/blob/master/src/app/product-list/product-detail.component.ts#L35); You may ask, what is cd? why need cd.markForCheck? Please refer to [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#observables).

Comment: getProduct(id: number) {
    this._productService.getProduct(id).subscribe(
      product => {this.product = product; this.cd.markForCheck();},
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the safe navigation operator in your template `?.`

This is because the asynchronous nature of the request.

So in your template you will change something that looks like `model.productName` to `model?.productName`.

Answer (score 0):

in the service

service name : GetProductService

```
getProduct(id: number) {
try {
  const url = `${this.url}/${id}`;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  this.http.get<Product>(url)
      .subscribe(response => {
          resolve(response);
        },
        error => {
          reject(error);
        }));
  }catch (exception) {
    console.log(exception.message);
  }
}

interface Product {
productId: number;
  .....
}
```

In the TypeScriptFile

```
private getProduct: GetProductService

SelectedProduct: Product = {productId: 0, title: ''... };

    try {
        const promise = this.getSiteOffice.getSiteOfficeDetails(this.siteOfficeId);
        promise.then(response => {
           this.SelectedProduct.productId = response['productId'];
           ...
        });
    }catch (exeption) {
      console.log(exeption.message);
    }

interface Product {
    productId: number;
    .....
}
```